# "Balanced" graphs and trees

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

Let $\Gamma$ be a graph with $n$ vertices. Assume for simplicity that there no loops or double edges. Denote by $A$ its (symmetric) adjacency matrix. We say that $\Gamma$ is "balanced" if

$$A x= \left[ \begin{array}{c}1 \\ 1 \\ .. \\ .. \\ 1 \end{array} \right]$$

has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}^n$.

For instance, the path of length two with three vertices

o---o---o

$$A=\left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{array}\right]$$

is balanced because $x=[1/2,1,1/2]^T$ is a solution.

Clearly, any graph whose adjacency matrix is invertible is balanced. But there are many additional examples. For instance any path with $n=4k+3$ number of vertices is balanced ($n=3$ given above) even though $\det(A)=0$.

**Question 1. Is there a nice characterization of balanced graphs?**

Comment 1. As far as I know there is no nice characterization of graphs with invertible adjacency matrix, so perhaps a better question would be:

**Question 2. Is there a nice characterization of balanced trees?**

Comment 2. It is known that a tree has a (unique) perfect matching if and only if its 
adjacency matrix is invertible.